Why is DatagramSocket receive() discard packets while MulticastSocket is not? On remote server
I try to

understand how i should work with server sockets for receiving data from remote client.
why when client on vpn data not losing.

I have client and server application with UDP sockets.
When i test it in LAN, all works without problem. But when server started at remote hosting data lost.
The fact is that when client connected to VPN client and server do sending and receiving properly.
The client code like that.
var serverConnection = new DatagramSocket();
// send registration to static ip (main server socket)
String portStr = String.valueOf(serverConnection.getLocalPort());
DatagramPacket registration = new DatagramPacket(
            portStr.getBytes(),
            portStr.getBytes().length,
            remoteServerIP,
            8560
        );
serverConnection.send(registration);
// receiving information about new "client manager" socket on server
serverConnection.receive(response);
int port = Integer.parseInt(new String(response.getData()));
var group = new InetSocketAddress(remoteServerIP, port);
// code for open streams...
// Thread for sending
 DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(audioBuffer, sampleRate, group);
 while (true) {
     if (micIsOn && micro.available() > 0) {
         micro.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.length);
             serverConnection.send(packet);
       }
 }
// Thread for receiving
  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(audioBuffer, outputLine.getBufferSize());
  while (true) {
        try {
            serverConnection.receive(packet);
            outputLine.write(
                 audioBuffer,
                 0,
                 outputLine.getBufferSize()
            );
            outputLine.drain();
            outputLine.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.log(ERROR, "End output audio!", e);
        }
  }

The server code i tried and work LAN is
// When start create main server soket this.serverAudio = new MulticastSocket(8560);
// after start Thread for register client and start receiving for other
serverAudio.receive(clientRegistration);
var client = new Client(
    clientRegistration.getAddress(),
    clientRegistration.getPort()
);
**DatagramSocket sender = new DatagramSocket();** // client manager on server side. Not work when DatagramSocket.
String portStr = String.valueOf(sender.getLocalPort());
serverAudio.send(new DatagramPacket(
    portStr.getBytes(),
    portStr.getBytes().length,
    client.address(),
    client.port()
));
startResend(sender, client, socketGroup);

Server code that semi work on remote host. Just change Datagram to Multicast.
// When start create main server soket this.serverAudio = new MulticastSocket(8560);
// after start Thread for register client and start receiving for other
serverAudio.receive(clientRegistration);
var client = new Client(
    clientRegistration.getAddress(),
    clientRegistration.getPort()
);
**MulticastSocket sender = new MulticastSocket ();** // client manager on server side. Receive but lost data when send to client.
String portStr = String.valueOf(sender.getLocalPort());
serverAudio.send(new DatagramPacket(
    portStr.getBytes(),
    portStr.getBytes().length,
    client.address(),
    client.port()
));
startResend(sender, client, socketGroup);

Resend method
// resend method
    private void startResend(
        DatagramSocket sender,
        Client client,
        SocketGroup socketGroup
    )
        throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        var packet = new DatagramPacket(
            buffer,
            BUFFER_SIZE // 44100 same as client
        );
        var toGroup = new DatagramPacket(
            buffer,
            BUFFER_SIZE,
            socketGroup.mcastaddr() // 225.x.x.x
        );
        var toClient = new DatagramPacket(
            buffer,
            BUFFER_SIZE,
            client.address(),
            client.port()
        );
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    sender.receive(packet); // never receive when 'sender' is instance of DatagramSocket. But receive when MulticastSocket
                    if (packet.getAddress().equals(client.address())
                        && packet.getPort() == client.port()
                    ) {
                        sender.send(toGroup);
                        continue;
                    }
                    sender.send(toClient);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error", e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


If the system works as expected when running in one network environment but not in another, then you should suspect an issue with the network environment. In particular, it is likely that your remote hosting site protects the machines it is hosting with a firewall that blocks traffic to most ports on the hosted machines.  Your provider's documentation and / or technical support resources should tell you about that.  If that is indeed the issue then your hosting provider you'll need either to sort it out with the provider or to work around it via ssh tunneling or similar.

Thank's for your response. I found that server not receive packets if it buffer array size is bigger than some value. I'v trie to send packet with 44100 size of voice data. But server accept only small packets with ~4k size. I hope my research was helpful.
